# Xamarin.Forms отступы между компонентами в StackLayout

Tags: xaml, xamarin

Имею TabbedPage с тремя страницами. На первой странице расположен StackLayout, который включает в себя повторяющиеся элементы(набор Label). Всё хорошо, только между Label имеются отступы. Margin у Label стоит в 0. Код:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="test_1.TabbedPage1"
            Title="New application"
            BarBackgroundColor="#806c9d">

    <!--Pages can be added as references or inline-->

    <ContentPage Title="Коробки">
        <StackLayout>

            <Label BackgroundColor="#f1c9ca" HeightRequest="3"  Margin="0,0,0,0"></Label>
            <Label BackgroundColor="#f1c9ca" HeightRequest="3"  Margin="0,0,0,0"></Label>
            <Label BackgroundColor="#f1c9ca" HeightRequest="3"  Margin="0,0,0,0"></Label>


        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage>
    <ContentPage Title="Букеты" />
    <ContentPage Title="NULL" />



</TabbedPage>
```

Что я упускаю? Мне надо, чтобы эти метки были вплотную друг к другу, без белого пробела между ними.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

StackLayout.Spacing имеет значение по умолчанию 6. это и есть ваши пробелы. установите в 0.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.stacklayout.spacing?view=xamarin-forms